# PHP - if-statement not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I am currently in a project to make an auction website. To make sure people can't bid too little above the current bid, I have made this if-statement:

```
if(
    ($this->getHighestBid() < 50 && $this->getHighestBid() >= 0 && $bid > $this->getHighestBid()+0.50) ||
    ($this->getHighestBid() < 500 && $this->getHighestBid() >= 50 && $bid > $this->getHighestBid()+1) ||
    ($this->getHighestBid() < 1000 && $this->getHighestBid() >= 500 && $bid > $this->getHighestBid()+5) ||
    ($this->getHighestBid() < 5000 && $this->getHighestBid() >= 1000 && $bid > $this->getHighestBid()+10) ||
    ($this->getHighestBid() >= 5000 && $bid > $this->getHighestBid()+50)            
){
...
}
```

This should make it so that when the current highest bid is in a specified range, you have to raise the price by at least the price specified.
My problem here is that it won't let me bid on anything at all. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: At first glance I believe you could probably do with storing `$this->getHighestBid()` in a variable.

Comment: Might I suggest you change this and simply create a `$this->getMinimumBidIncrement()` method to handle the logic you're writing here? It would certainly make things easier to read and understand.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't approach it based on a percentage value of the highest bid instead, for example bids have be exceed the highest bid by more than 10%: `if (($bid - $this->getHighestBid()) <= ($this->getHighestBid() / 10)) {}`

Comment: @MLeFevre I was planning to do that at first, but eventually we settled with this system because the members of the project found this more effective.

Comment: you should put like this  (($this->getHighestBid() < 50) && ($this->getHighestBid() >= 0))

Comment: Side note, your code works on [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/4OWVG), do you have a sample that doesn't?

Comment: @scragar That's quite strange. I tried an echo in my original code in both the if and the else, which showed that it would go into the else no matter what.

Comment: Could you do a var_dump of the `$this->getHighestBid()` to confirm that it's a float/integer? If it's a string it would explain the possibility of you getting strange outputs, as would the highest bid being below zero for some reason.

Comment: @scragar Hm. It shows it as being a string(7). I guess the problem lies there; it just comes down to converting it to a float then.

Comment: @scragar Could you post that last thing you said as answer, so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work in my testing, it sounds like the type of the variable is not a numeric type(float or integer) and is actually a string or similarly strange type.

To confirm:

```
var_dump($this->getHighestBid());
```

I would like to add while I'm writing my answer though that you will probably want to edit your code to read more like:

```
function getMinimumBid() {
     $maxBid = (float)$this->getHighestBid();
     return $maxBid + $this->getBidIncrement();
}

function getBidIncrement() {
     $maxBid = (float)$this->getHighestBid();
     switch (true) {
          case $maxBid < 50:
              return 0.50;
          case $maxBid < 500:
              return 1;
          case $maxBid < 1000:
              return 5;
          case $maxBid < 5000:
              return 10;
          default:
              return 50;
     }
}

// ...
    if ($bid >= $this->getMinimumBid()) {
    }
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's your code:

```
$highest_bid = $this->getHighestBid();
if(
    ($highest_bid < 50 && $highest_bid >= 1 && $bid > ($highest_bid+0.50)) ||
    ($highest_bid < 500 && $highest_bid >= 50 && $bid > ($highest_bid+1)) ||
    ($highest_bid < 1000 && $highest_bid >= 500 && $bid > ($highest_bid+5)) ||
    ($highest_bid < 5000 && $highest_bid >= 1000 && $bid > ($highest_bid+10)) ||
    ($highest_bid >= 5000 && $bid > ($highest_bid+50))       
){
    // Condition 1:
    // Highest bid should be >= 1 and < 50
    // Bid should be > 1.5 and < 50.5

    // Condition 2:
    // Highest bid should be >= 50 and < 500
    // Bid should be > 51 and < 501

    // Condition 3:
    // Highest bid should be >= 500 and < 1000
    // Bid should be > 505 and < 1005

    // Condition 4:
    // Highest bid should be >= 1000 and < 5000
    // Bid should be > 1010 and < 5010

    // Condition 5:
    // Highest bid should be >= 5000
    // Bid should be > 5050
}
```

There's a major problem here:

- there's some numbers which aren't handled.
- you should consider doing this business logic in a function.

Comment: His code already works, as evidenced by the [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/4OWVG) I made, your code however doesn't, downvoted for posting broken code in response to good code that has another problem.

Comment: How exactly are those numbers not handled? I have added >= in the meantime where needed, and this if-statement is already in a function.

Comment: What I mean is that a bid with 502 will go into the "else" part of the statement.
The code I provided works but you need to assign the `$bid` and the `$this->getHighestBid()`.
I just cleaned up the code and provided an explanation.

Comment: `echo $bid . ' -- ' . $this->getHighestBid();`.
Write this code before the if statement, so you can check the values of the variables, otherwise it'll be really hard for us to help you.

Comment: @Wissam El-Kik Try an input max bid of 500, does your code work?

Comment: I tried it with the following values:
`$bid = 500; $highest_bid = 400;`
and it went inside the if statement. The problem is in the Business Logic I guess. The code is error-free.

Comment: @Wissam El-Kik Try with a highest bid of 500, it's a bug in your version of the code, his works fine.

Comment: Yep it's not gonna work because I didn't add the equal sign.
In the original code, there wasn't an equal sign, and this isn't a PHP error, it's a business logic error.
I added the equal sign according to the updated code provided by the user above.

Answer (score -1):

I changed your code a little bit, so I could execute it in my IDE:

```
    <?php
    $hbid = 50;
    $bid = 52;
if(
    ($hbid < 50 && $hbid >= 0 && $bid > $hbid+0.50) ||
    ($hbid < 500 && $hbid >= 50 && $bid > $hbid+1) ||
    ($hbid < 1000 && $hbid >= 500 && $bid > $hbid+5) ||
    ($hbid < 5000 && $hbid >= 1000 && $bid > $hbid+10) ||
    ($hbid >= 5000 && $bid > $hbid+50)            
)
{
    echo "ok";
}
else
{
    echo 'not ok';
}
?>
```

When I change the parameters, it always works fine. I guess your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: There's a typo here: `$$hbid`